# Problems using Greater than and Less than with Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am having issues using greater than and less than in an IF statement, for some reason the statement keeps getting truncated, it's like they system is seeing this as an HTML tag even though it is in brackets.

Has anyone has this issue?

```
%%[IF @curGPA > '2.24' AND ( @Grade == 'A' OR @Grade == 'B' OR @Grade == 'C' ) THEN]%%
    %%=ContentBlockbyID('37122')=%% 
%%[ELSEIF ( @Grade == 'D' OR @Grade == 'F' ) THEN]%% 
    %%=ContentBlockbyID('38793')=%% 
%%[ELSE]%% 
    %%=ContentBlockbyID('37123')=%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Do you get an error message, you can share? (For readability I updated the code to just an ELSE instead of a condition that would pretty much work as an ELSE, as you said  in the other comment that you tried that before)

Comment: Yes, it is an error with formatnumber function: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a FormatNumber function call. See inner exception for details.
 Function Call: Formatnumber(@curGPA, 'D2')

Comment: And with your original code, which error do you receive? Or what exactly is the unexpected behavior? Is the expression unevaluated at all and you don't see any content block?

Comment: The expression does not evaluate the  condition with the '>', only the second and the default 'ELSE' Statement

Comment: Please update your question to include the code that sets `@curGPA`

Comment: It is simply a variable SET @curGPA = [curGPA]

Comment: Did you try printing this variable? Maybe it doesn't contain the expected value?

Comment: Yes, It has the expected value, I am using a test list with one record for each possible scenario. The values all display correctly when referenced. They also populate correctly if we use a Dynamic Content Module with these rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something like this that utilizes the [**Add()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/add/) function set the data type.  I'd also output the values for verification.

```
%%[

var @curGPA, @grade
set @grade = AttributeValue("grade")
set @curGPA = AttributeValue("curGPA")
set @curGPA = Add(@curGPA,0.0)
output(concat("<br>@curGPA: ",@curGPA))
output(concat("<br>@grade : ",@grade ))

]%%

%%[ IF @curGPA > 2.24 AND ( @Grade == 'A' OR @Grade == 'B' OR @Grade == 'C' ) THEN]%%

    %%=ContentBlockbyID('37122')=%% 

%%[ELSEIF ( @Grade == 'D' OR @Grade == 'F' ) THEN]%% 

    %%=ContentBlockbyID('38793')=%% 

%%[ELSE]%% 

    %%=ContentBlockbyID('37123')=%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: I think that may have worked, I am testing it now

Comment: So this actually does work but it creates a new issue in that there is a separate set of rules for anyone with the @curGPA that does not have a value. But I think I can resolve that.